# How to write code for truth tables that and or gates

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have created a table in a database with 2 columns and I filled those two columns with 1's and 0's. On the frontend I have tdbgrid which displays those values from the database. When I click on a button

- if I have 1 and 0  in the 3rd column it has to display 0.
- if it is 1 and 1 then 1.

This is the code that I have written but it is not showing in grid.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  i := ADODataSet1.FieldByName('id').AsInteger;
  j := ADODataSet1.FieldByName('id2').AsInteger;
  ADODataSet1.First;
  while not ADODataSet1.Eof do
  begin
    if (i = j) and (i<>j) then
    begin
      ShowMessage('true');
      //  Exit;
    end
    Else
      ShowMessage('false');
      //Exit;
    ADODataSet1.Next;
  end;
end;
```

how to write that code.

Comment: What particular part of the problem is causing you trouble. Please show code and indicate where you are stuck.

Comment: Could you ever imaging a situation where `(i = j) and (i <> j)` gets true? Two values must be equal and non equal at the same time?

Comment: Your code can be reduced to `ShowMessage('false'); ADODataSet1.Bottom;'

Comment: It was wrong That I have done.. but unfortunately I have copied it like that..I am struck there.. how can I write code for both and as well as or also..

Comment: We did not have a clue what you are trying to do. So please put some more details into your question (what data do you have and what result do you expect from that). We can not look onto your screen or inside your head

Comment: @SirRufo I have created a table in database with 2 columns and I filled those two columns with 1's and 0's.. on frontend I have tdbgrid which displays those values from database when I click on button if I have 1 and 0.. in the 3rd column it has to display 0.. if it is 1 and 1 then 1..Thank you.. I am sorry.. My question wasn't clear 2 you before..

Comment: Add this details to the question (edit) and do not provide this inside the comments

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement an OR gate:

```
if (i = 1) or  (j = 1) then
  ShowMessage('true')
else
  ShowMessage('false');
```

If you want to implement an AND gate:

```
if (i = 1) and (j = 1) then
  ShowMessage('true')
else
  ShowMessage('false');
```

Also your logic is flawed, i and j are never updated:

```
ADODataSet1.First;
while not ADODataSet1.Eof do
begin
  i := ADODataSet1.FieldByName('id').AsInteger;
  j := ADODataSet1.FieldByName('id2').AsInteger;

  // Magic happens here

  ADODataSet1.Next;
end;
```

Next you can use boolean variables to cleanup the code:

```
var
  A,B,C : Boolean;
begin
  ADODataSet1.First;
  while not ADODataSet1.Eof do
  begin
    A := ADODataSet1.FieldByName('id').AsInteger = 1;
    B := ADODataSet1.FieldByName('id2').AsInteger = 1;

    // OR
    C := A or B;

    // AND
    C := A and B;

    // Do something with C.
    ShowMessage(BoolToStr(C));

    ADODataSet1.Next;
  end;
end;
```

And don't forget to handle any errors (for example what if a 2 is found in a field.

Comment: Thank you.. Toon.. once we get a values of c how can we bind that values to Tdbgrid when I click on button.. Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Your third column has to be a **calculated** field (name it *Result*) and you should add this field to your dataset otherwise you are not able to show it inside the grid.

[Defining a Calculated Field](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Defining_a_Calculated_Field)

Add an event handler for your dataset `ADODataSet1.OnCalcFields`

[Programming a Calculated Field](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Programming_a_Calculated_Field)

```
procedure TYourForm.ADODataSet1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if ( DataSet['id'] = 1 ) and ( DataSet['id2'] = 1 ) then
    DataSet['Result'] := 1
  else
    DataSet['Result'] := 0;
end;
```